# Correctly set the current user as the new owner in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to set a new owner in Powershell but the problem is that I dont know exactly what to put

I have this:

```
$person="Bob"
$acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] $person)
```

But what I need to put is a username that I grab from the current user that is logged in.

How do I get the current user logged in?

Comment: So:

$person="Bob"
$acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] $env:USERNAME)

Comment: no, just $acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] $env:USERNAME). You should invest some time and search / try yourself before you ask here